# Questions about the random variable when viewing it as a measurable function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(\Omega,P(\Omega),u)$ be a probability space. Let $\textbf{X}_1,\dots,\textbf{X}_n,\dots$ be a sequence of independent, identically distributed, integrable random variables defined on the previous probability space. Suppose $E(\textbf{X}_i)=m, \forall i=1,2,3,\dots$. The Strong Law of Large Numbers says that for almost every sample point $\omega\in\Omega$,
$$
\frac{\textbf{X}_1(\omega)+\dots+\textbf{X}_n(\omega)}{n}\rightarrow m, \text{as} \, n\rightarrow \infty.
$$

I'm very confused by the definition of a random variable as a measurable function. If we are given a certain $\omega\in \Omega$, shouldn't $\frac{\textbf{X}_1(\omega)+\dots+\textbf{X}_n(\omega)}{n}$ be a fixed value? Where does the randomness come in the above average formula? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The randomness comes from $\Omega$. We don't know the outcome of our experiment, so we don't know what $\omega$ we will get. But once we know $\omega$, then $\bf{X_i}(\omega)$ is fixed, not random.

Comment: So, are $\omega$s in $\frac{\textbf{X}_1(\omega)+\dots+\textbf{X}_n(\omega)}{n}$ the same? If they are the same outcome, shouldn't the final $X_i(\omega)$ be the same for all $i=1,2,\dots$? I don't understand how different trials are embedded in the formula.

Comment: @XianjinYang For a fixed $\omega$, you don't generally have $X_i(\omega) = X_j(\omega)$ when $i \neq j$. If this were the case, the random variables wouldn't be independent. The random variables are identically distributed, but this doesn't mean they are all the same function of $\omega$.

Comment: @Bungo can you give an example about i.i.d $\textbf{X}_1,\dots,\textbf{X}_n$, and $\textbf{X}_i \neq \textbf{X}_j$ when $i\neq j$? If we specify a common $\omega$, does it mean that we have the same outcomes in all the trials?

Comment: @XianjinYang Let $\Omega = [0,1]$. Define $X_1(\omega) = 1$ for $\omega \in [0,1/2]$ and $X_1(\omega) = -1$ for $\omega \in (1/2, 1]$. Define $X_2(\omega) = 1$ if $\omega \in [0,1/4)\cup[1/2,3/4)$ and $X_2(\omega) = -1$ if $\omega \in [1/4,1/2)\cup[3/4,1]$. In general, $X_n(\omega) = 1$ on intervals of the form $[k/2^n, (k+1)/2^n)$ where $k$ is even, and $X_n(\omega) = -1$ on the remaining intervals. You can check that these are i.i.d. Each $X_n$ is $1$ or $-1$ with equal probability.

Comment: If we specify a common $\omega$ for each $\textbf{X}_i$, does it mean that we have the same outcomes in all the trials?

Comment: @Bungo If we specify a common $\omega$ for each $\textbf{X}_i$, does it mean that we have the same outcomes in all the trials? I think a random variable only serves to give an numerical valuie to an outcome. If $\omega$ is given, an outcome is fixed. If we give all $\textbf{X}_i$ the same $\omega$, there must be a problem.

Comment: @XianjinYang If the $X_i$ are jointly distributed, then yes, there is a single outcome $\omega$ which simultaneously determines the values of each random variable. Have you learned about product measures?

Comment: @Bungo Yes, I learnt it. But in this case, the variables are independent. We only specify a single $\omega$, does it mean the outcomes are the same? If they are the same, it should have a problem here. If they are not, why does the expression use the same parameter $\omega$?

Comment: "We only specify a single ω, does it mean the outcomes are the same?" You already asked this three times, no? And got twice the same answer: yes $\omega$ is the same, no the $X_k(\omega)$ are not (necessarily) the same for different $k$s. Sure you want to go on?

Comment: @Did yes. I understand their answers. My question is if the $\omega$s are the same, the outcomes of the experiments are the same.  Right? But it contradicts our intuition that the outcomes of each experiment should be different. So, I must make something wrong here.

Comment: No, not right. Think about two functions $f$ and $g$. For some given $x$ ("the same"), the values $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ can be different, right? This is the setting of your question.

Comment: @Did Yes, that's my original question. According to this answer I have another question. Based on my understanding, $\omega$ is the outcome. The random variable assign a real value to the outcome. For example, if we toss a coin, there are 2 outcomes.  We assign one outcome to a real value 1 and let another be 0. If we specify a single $\omega$, it seems that the outcomes of all the trials are the same even they are assigned different real values. For example, all the trials have the upside of the coin up. It contradicts our intuition, right? So, I'm confused by this.

Comment: @XianjinYang Even if two jointly distributed random variables are independent and identically distributed, **they are not the same function**.  They can give different values for the same $\omega$. Please carefully examine the example I gave in comment #4 above. Note the following things: the $X_n$ are independent and identically distributed, and no two of them are the same function. A single $\omega$ simultaneously generates independent values for each random variable.

Comment: @XianjinYang With regard to your coin tossing example, if we toss, say, 10 coins, then a single outcome may be something like the string $\omega = HTTHHTHTTT$ or the vector $\omega = (H,T,T,H,H,T,H,T,T,T)$. Then $X_n(\omega)$ is $1$ or $0$ depending on whether the $n$th entry in this string or vector if $H$ or $T$. A third possibility is the one I outlined in comment #4 above. The specific construction of the sample space doesn't matter for most purposes. In all cases, the $X_n$ are jointly distributed and i.i.d, assuming $1$ or $0$ with equal probability.

Comment: @Bungo I see. So, do you mean that in the coin tossing example, if we toss a coin 10 times, then the sample space is $\Omega=\{H,T\}^{10}$? Then, a single sample point may be $\omega=\{H,T,T,H,H,T,H,T,T,T\}$. If it is true. Now let's consider a random process, $X(t,\omega)$. What's the sample space of the random process? It may very hard to express the sample space as a Cartesian product in this case. How to do that?

Comment: @XianjinYang We can start by defining a measure for each finite set $\{t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_k\}$, of times (or whatever $t$ denotes), then apply the [Kolmogorov extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem)